# Change color to the selected element

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I dont want it like in http://jsfiddle.net/zNTqm/287/.
I want to style the shown selected element

```
<select class="mySelect">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option> <---- the shown element should be RED 
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't style 'option' tags like that, plus you only see the selected option anyway, so you could try

```
div class='hightlight'>
 [select code goes here]
</div>
```

Then style the background of your highlight div (making sure its bigger then the select so its nice and noticable. Or you could add a border to the select to show an option has been selected etc

Comment: this is what i thought : a div with a color which depends on the selection event, i thought there is a css option to stlye the selected directly without a div, guss not

Comment: its more that you can not style a native option tag in css, you'd have to either style another element and use that to fake the option tag or style the select (which only allows some styling options)